# python - problem with invoking sockets command: winerror 10022

Tags: python, sockets

This is my code (for windows 7):

```
sock=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
address=('224.1.1.1', 1900)
sock.bind(address)
sock.settimeout(0)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
sock.ioctl(socket.SIO_RCVALL, socket.RCVALL_ON)
```

On the last row I'm getting: winerror 10022

Why do I get it?

Comment: wich python version are you using?

Comment: @Avatazjoe -  3.6.5

Answer (score 0):

10022 is "Invalid argument". Your socket is not correct for ioctl.

From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/winsock-ioctls :

> **SIO_RCVALL**
>
> Enables a socket to receive all IPv4 or IPv6 packets passing throuigh
> a network interface. The socket handle passed to the WSAIoctl function
> must be one of the following:
>
> - An IPv4 socket that was created with the address family set to AF_INET, the socket type set to SOCK_RAW, and the protocol set to
>   IPPROTO_IP.
> - An IPv6 socket that was created with the address family set to AF_INET6, the socket type set to SOCK_RAW, and the protocol set to
>   IPPROTO_IPV6.

Only members of the Administrators group can create sockets of type SOCK_RAW on Windows 2000 and later.

Comment: OK, I've updated to the following one, but still getting the same error on  same row `socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.IPPROTO_IP)`

Comment: Only members of the Administrators group can create sockets of type SOCK_RAW. The above code must be run with administrator rights. Try launching Python with administrator rights. Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/tcp-ip-raw-sockets-2

Comment: I've started spyder with run as administrator and same error